# Dependency conflict in project.json

Tags: asp.net-core, project.json

We do our versioning based on the year,month and day. We are constantly updating the versions because we use the libraries in nuget packages and we need to be able to differentiate between versions.

I am getting the warning :

> Dependency specified was Project.Public >= 2017.* but ended up with
>   Project.Public 2017.2.22-a.   Project.ClientTest  D:\path\project.json

The application still works fine but I am sure this version mismatch could cause issues down the road.

How do I fix my `project.json` so I do not get this warning?

Comment: After a little more research it looks like this should work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution#floating-versions  

I am wondering if the warning is just a false positive.